# Помогите с питоном, функция for i in range пожайлустааааа

Tags: python

Цифры числа
Дано 10-значное число. Выведите все цифры этого числа в обратном порядке по одной.

Входные данные

На вход подаётся натуральное 10-значное число.

Выходные данные

Выведите ответ на задачу. В качестве разделителя между цифрами можно использовать переводы строки и пробелы.

Примеры
Ввод
Вывод
1234567890
0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 3):

```
print(*input()[::-1])
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Программа не соответствует требованиям:
в коде программы используется массив, что запрещено условиями задачи
Я просил решить через функцию for

Comment: @ПавелПоцелуйко во первых в вашем вопросе о массива ничего не говорится, а во вторых тут нету массива есть только строки

Comment: @ПавелПоцелуйко, `[::-1]` это оператор среза :)

Answer (score 2):

Если сильно нужен именно `for`:

```
num = input()
for i in range(len(num)-1, -1, -1):
    print(num[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = input()
print(' '.join(reversed([i for i in nums])))
```

Comment: `str` тут лишний.